# wcf tcp: error 10061

Tags: wcf, tcp

I have a service with two contracts that I want to use with tcp binding. The service configuration files is this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceDocumentos" transferMode="Streamed"
                 maxBufferSize="67108864"
                      maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" maxBufferPoolSize="67108864"
                   closeTimeout="00:00:10"
                       openTimeout="00:00:10" receiveTimeout="00:20:00"
                       sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxConnections="100"/>
        <binding name="ServiceCore" transferMode="Buffered"
                 maxBufferSize="67108864"
                      maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" maxBufferPoolSize="67108864"
                   closeTimeout="00:00:10"
                       openTimeout="00:00:10" receiveTimeout="00:20:00"
                       sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxConnections="100"/>
      </netTcpBinding>

      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceDocumentos" messageEncoding="Mtom" transferMode="Streamed"  />
        <binding name="ServiceCore" messageEncoding="Mtom" transferMode="Buffered" />
      </basicHttpBinding>

      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceDocumentos" messageEncoding="Mtom"/>
        <binding name="ServiceCore" messageEncoding="Mtom"/>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="CMMSService" name="GTS.CMMS.Service.Service">
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceDocumentos"
                 name="ServiceDocumentos" contract="GTS.CMMS.Service.IServiceDocumentos"
         address="ServiceDocumentos/">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address ="net.tcp://localhost:6000/CMMSService/ServiceCore/"
                 binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceCore"
                 name="ServiceCore" contract="GTS.CMMS.Service.IService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"
                 listenUriMode="Explicit">
        </endpoint>

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8500/CMMSService" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8501/CMMSService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>


      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CMMSService">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And the client configuration file is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceDocumentos" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
         receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferSize="3670016" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="3670016"
         transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="65536"
           maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="ServiceCore" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
         receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferSize="2097152" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152"
         transferMode="Buffered">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="65536"
           maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>

      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceDocumentos" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
         receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
         bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferSize="3670016" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="3670016"
         messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed"
         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="65536"
           maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="ServiceCore" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
         receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
         bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferSize="2097152" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152"
         messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="65536"
           maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
             realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceDocumentos" messageEncoding="Mtom"/>
        <binding name="ServiceCore" messageEncoding="Mtom"/>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <!--<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8501/CMMSService/ServiceDocumentos/"
       binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceDocumentos"
       contract="IServiceDocumentos" name="ServiceDocumentos" />
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8501/CMMSService/ServiceCore/"
       binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceCore"
       contract="IService" name="ServiceCore" />-->

      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8501/CMMSService/ServiceDocumentos/"
       binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceDocumentos"
       contract="IServiceDocumentos" name="ServiceDocumentos" />
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:6000/CMMSService/ServiceCore/"
       binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceCore"
       contract="IService" name="ServiceCore" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I am doing test with different bindings. For example, if for one contract, IServiceDocumentos I use tcp and for the other contract, the main contract I use wsDualHttpBinding, all works fine. Ican use the two contracts.

If I use tcp for the two contracts, then I get the error tcp 10061.

I try to use a individual full address for each contract, because I guess that the problem could be the use of the same port, but the problem persists. However, if I use a full individual address for each endpoint, that works if I use different bindings.

Also I try to star the service tcp port sharing (the service in windows XP) and the problem is not solved.

I try to disabled the firewall, but this not solve the problem.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I use the follwing command when I have the service running:

```
netstat -ona || find "6000"
```

I get the following information:

TCP      0.0.0.0:6000     0.0.0.0     LISTENING      2690

So I think that the por is opened and listening.

Comment: Error `10061` is "Connection refused" (`WSAECONNREFUSED`). This means that the computer you are trying to connect to is not listening. Is the application running on that computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have defined your addressees of your service endpoints in the wrong way.
You don't have to use a different port for each tcp address as long as you enable port sharing.
That is achieved by using Net.TCP Port Sharing Service which is available on any .NET 3.0 installation. By default the service is not enabled so you have to enable it yourself. Related to how to enable Net.TCP POrt Sharing Service check the follwoing link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733925.aspx.

Comment: I test it with the service started, but I get the same error, so I think that the problem is not the sharing of the tcp port.

I add some information in the original post.